# ERROR: Error installing json: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

I am trying to install gem json and getting error for json.

I'm running:

- Windows 8.1 (64 bit)
- Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
- gem: 1.8.2

```
D:\GIT\calabash>gem install json -v '1.8.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR: Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

D:\GIT\calabash>
```

Comment: [JSON is already bundled with 1.9.3.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html) Why are you trying to reinstall it? Why not install a current and supported version of Ruby instead?

Answer (score 3):

Its a late response, but may it helps someone else. to install json '1.8.3' it requires packages 'libgmp3-dev'.

Use following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev

gem install json -v '1.8.3'
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem on Ubuntu either.

Answer (score 1):

To help you here are some steps to follow in order to install your gem locally:

1. Download  [json-1.8.3](https://rubygems.org/gems/json/versions/1.8.3).
2. Place the downloaded gem into a folder called `gems`
3. Open the Ruby `cmd` console (click on start button, select Ruby then select  "Start  command prompt with Ruby")
4. `cd` to the gems folder. If the path to the folder is `C:\Desktop\gems`, write the command: `cd C:\Desktop\gems` then click "Enter".
5. To install the gem run the following command:

   ```
   gem install --local json-1.8.3.gem
   ```

I tried it and it worked for me, hopefully it will work for you.

Result:
[image]

---

Second way:

Include the whole path  of the gem in the command:

```
gem install --local C:\Users\kedarl\Desktop\T\json-1.8.2.gem
```

For me here is the result. (This time with the json-1.8.2.gem):

[image]

Comment: it show another error i.e.
C:\Users\kedarl\Desktop\T>gem install --local json-1.8.3.gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing json-1.8.3.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out

Comment: Is Devkit installed in your machine

Comment: Yes.
C:\Devkit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v1.9.3 at C:/Ruby193
Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\Devkit>ruby dk.rb install --force
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

Comment: I updated devkit\bin path and -> 

C:\Users\kedarl\Desktop\T>gem install --local json-1.8.3.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing json-1.8.3.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out

Comment: I believe it is a problem of devkit version which one are you installing in your machine

Comment: Devkit Version : DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx
which version is recommended?

tried second way too, but observation is same.

I only set a single devkit path in user variable Path "C:\Devkit\bin"

Comment: That is the same version i have and it is the one that goes with ruby1.9.3, all that you can do now is delete that version and try to install it again follwing these steps:http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/1-ruby-and-devkit/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has this issue on Sierra, I solved the problem through this thread: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/installing-ruby-on-mac-got-error

Coles notes version is that after updating to most recent version of XCode, I had to accept the terms for the XCode command line tools. See them/agree to them by running:

```
gcc --version
```

After I did that, everything installed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by installing Command Line Tools Xcode of the version I have. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you installed Rails through RailsInstaller, try this -

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

It's a pretty common bug for RailsInstaller currently.