# Bundle install fails on windows

Tags: ruby, heroku

Installing Heroku on Windows 8.1 on Ruby, "bundle install" fails with the following error. 
All dependencies have been install.
How can I fix this?

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: what is your ruby and rails versions

Comment: Ruby: 2.2.3p173  Gem: 2.5  Rails: 4.2.4

Comment: try to look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138639/error-error-installing-json-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: Thanks, I'm gettting the same error with the local install as before:                      >gem install --local json-1.8.3.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json-1.8.3.gem:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151105-8328-102ugbv.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile


failed, exit code 2