# Getting Error when trying to install json in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Related Question: [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138639/error-error-installing-json-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

I am trying to make ruby on rails (ruby 2.0.0p647 (2015-08-18) [x64-mingw32]) to work on my system.
I'm running Windows 8.1 (64 bit)

The installation of ruby and rails goes smoothly but when i run `rails new blog`
I get the following error:

```
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
        .
        C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR="
    generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
    compiling generator.c
    linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
    c:/ruby200-x64/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../.
    ./../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
    c:/ruby200-x64/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../.
    ./../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [generator.so] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-
1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ex
t/generator/gem_make.out
Using minitest 5.8.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types 2.99
Using arel 6.0.3
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.
```

I have already tried installing ruby and the development kit 3 times (with different ruby versions)
I keep getting the same error.

I have tried the solution in the question above.

I get a very similar error:

```
    C:\Ruby200-x64>gem install --local json-1.8.3.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json-1.8.3.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
```

I have tried to reinstall ruby with different ruby version (the newest one)
as well as installing both of the x86 versions of ruby and the development kit which did nothing for me.

Comment: KelsyDH put together an excellent document on the topic of setting up a Windows box for RoR development: https://gist.github.com/KelseyDH/11198922. When I was setting up my Windows dev machine, Ruby 1.9.3 was newest version known to be stable on Windows. That was about a year ago. I don't know if that's changed.

Comment: just to be clear this is not only native extentions that fail. debug_inspector 0.0.2 also fails to build right after  and than  byebug 8.2.1

Comment: Yep. Windows. Spurious failures, hard to track down.  I would suggest you check with one of the Rails (the platform itself) developers on github and ask if RoR has been installed successfully on Win 8 by anyone. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer because I've not had an issue with JSON before; I'll tell you about the error itself though - just so you know what's going on.

---

Whenever you install a `gem` on your system, it needs certain files to run.

Most `gems` have all the files they need, but some need extra ones. `mysql2`,`rmagick` and `nokogiri` are some of these.

The `gems` which need extra files have to load "dependencies" from your system to help them install properly. They then *compile* the extra files with a `c compiler`. This is what `building native extensions` means.

When you install any gem, Ruby looks in `ext/extconf.rb` to see how to compile the extra files. This `extconf.rb` has compiler code which relies on the dependencies you add. This is why the error always says `extconf.rb failed`

--

You need a valid `C compiler` (DevKit includes `gcc`) and a make program (I believe Devkit includes `nmake`). Running `extconf.rb` with Ruby should use the `gcc` compiler in your PATH to create a `Makefile`. Running `make` on the `Makefile` will then build the gem's extra dependencies:

[image]

--

The most common form of this error is for [`mysql2`](https://medium.com/@frontlineutils/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3#.qxaidro2x):

[image]

The fix is to include the dependencies on your system, link to it and then install the gem again. EG:

```
 gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir="c:/path/to/mysql"
```

---

## JSON

It seems that JSON just has C headers which need to be compiled.

In this case, I would strongly recommend finding a new compiler & using it instead of Devkit. It might not work, but I think your JSON needs to be compiled rather than have extra dependencies.

We use MingW for compiling things in Windows.

Good ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593870/1143732

You can download our [MingW64 here](https://mega.nz/#!c4tGRSTb!FJtcq25l-QMsNltCxllMhc1IGqORvap8xv8gWxSUbDA), or [download it yourself](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

Install it & add it to your PATH. It will take the place of Devkit; its more robust for compiling gems.

Once you've done it, go to your `ruby\lib\ruby\gems\[version]\json...\ext`

Type `ruby extconf.rb` and see what happens. If it build a `Makefile`, type `make` and then `make install`

If not, post back what you found and we'll see if it gets fixed

Comment: by install MingW did you just mean unzip it and ad the bin folder to path?? I have tried to follow your directions and the ruby extconf.rb builds a Makefile. Make command outputs make: Nothing to be done. and make install outputs installing default libraries. I still get the same error when i run: rails new blog.

Comment: Yes exactly, you need to add the bin to path. There's nothing in extconf? Can you post the extconf and I'll see what it says

Comment: extconf path: "C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\json-1.8.3\ext\json"  content:
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('json')

Comment: What does `mkfmf` say (it should be in the same directory)?

Comment: mkmf.rb is in C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\2.0.0 directory and its too large to post.

Comment: can you put it on pastebin.com ?

Comment: Yes it's quite big lol. Do you mind if I look tomorrow? It's midnight in the UK right now :)

Comment: yea no problem, Thx for your help :)